# How to execute Pre-build Query in Java Spring

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I need to execute pre-build SQL query in java spring, I created query as follows,

```
String query = "select * from device where";

if (status != null) {
    query += " status = "+status;
}

if (cinema != "") {
    query += " and cinema_code = \'"+cinema+"\'";
}

if (content_profile != "") {
    query += " and content_profile = \'"+content_profile+"\'";
}

if (mac != "") {
    query += " and mac = \'"+mac+"\'";
}
```

Build query:

```
select * 
from device 
where status = 2 
  and cinema_code = 'AL10' 
  and content_profile = 'signage'
```

Comment: Your code is dangerous. Never use String concat to also include the parameters in your string. Use  a `PreparedStatement` to fill placeholders. That being said what do you use plain JDBC, JPA, Hibernate, JOOQ,... to execute queries.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have configured the Spring datasource you can execute a Spring native query using:

```
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
List<Object> results = em.createNativeQuery(query);
```

You should also update your query, because you can easily get a `SQLException` when status is null. If it happens you will have an invalid query:

```
select *
from device 
where and cinema_code = 'AL10' and content_profile = 'signage'
```

Try to use this initial query:

```
"select * from device where 1=1 "
```

Using the above, the query will be correct no matter if the first if is executed or no ifs executed at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring Data JPA Specifications for dynamic queries.
Give a look here:
https://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-search-language-spring-data-specifications

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want JPA you can use [Spring JDBC](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jdbc-jdbctemplate)

Execute query:

```java
String query = "select * from device where status = 2 and cinema_code = 'AL10' and content_profile = 'signage'";
List<Device> devices = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
    query, new Object[] { }, new DeviceRowMapper());
```

Mapper can look like this:

```java
public class DeviceRowMapper implements RowMapper<Device> {
    @Override
    public Employee mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        Device device = new Device();

        device.setId(rs.getInt("ID"));
        ...

        return device;
    }
}
```

How to config the connection in providing [url](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jdbc-jdbctemplate)

However as it was mentioned in comments. It is better not to concatenate string parameters.
Your query building can be done in that way.

```java
String query = "select * from device where";

List parameters =  new ArrayList();
boolean wasParameter = false;

if(status != null) {
    query += " status = ? ";
    parameters.add(status);
    wasParameter = true;
}

if(cinema != "") {
    query += (wasParameter ? " and ": "") +" cinema_code = ? ";
    parameters.add(cinema);
    wasParameter = true;
}

if(content_profile != "") {
    query += (wasParameter ? " and ": "") +" content_profile = ? ";
    parameters.add(content_profile);
    wasParameter = true;
}

if(mac != "") {
    query += (wasParameter ? " and ": "") +" mac = ? ";
    parameters.add(mac);
}

Object[] array = parameters.toArray(new Object[0]);
```

And execute query:

```java
List<Device> devices = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
    query, array, new DeviceRowMapper());
```